# Jenkins automated test download file Error

Tags: ruby, selenium, testing, jenkins, download

I hope you can help me with this.

I am running an automated test in ruby/cucumber with Selenium and Chrome, 
to verify that a file I click on is downloaded and saved. It works fine in RubyMine, but the nightly tests in Jenkins fail. The clicking works, the download verification doesnt. Do I need a different setting in Jenkins, or do I need to change some configurations, so that Jenkins can verify that the file is downloaded. I'm not really sure where Jenkins downloads the file to, I implemented a ruby method with "send_keys" for the download and folder.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, I am assuming you're saying it works fine in RubyMine because it's in your local machine right? Or are you executing the test remotely against a jenkins slave? Jenkins saves the file wherever you say it to save it in your code, it expects it to save it in the slave your jenkins job is executed.

Comment: Yeah sorry i am new to testing in jenkins and in general. it works fine in rubymine because its on my local machine. so i dont need any specifications in the jenkins settings or something? my work running in rubymine should also run on jenkins, since i say it in my code where it should be downloaded to, right?